# How to configure angular2 CLI in offline environment

Tags: angularjs, installation, offline, angular-cli

I have used the "http://webiks.com/working-offline-with-angular-cli/" resource to setup my angular2 and use angular cli for an offline environment that does not have access to Internet.

I appreciate if you explain how I can configure angular cli to use cli commands in offline environment.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Install it in online machine and copy

%appdata%/npm/node_modules/@angular
%appdata%/npm/ng
%appdata%/npm/ng.cmd
Paste these in the same path in offline machine and run “ng -v” from cmd to verify…All done[Refer](https://discventionstech.wordpress.com/2017/04/10/install-angular-cli-offline/)